# copy all files to a library using apex Salesforce

Tags: content, execute-anonymous

I am trying to pass several files through the anonymous window to a library using ContentWorkspaceDoc, someone can help me.

this is my code:

```
List<ContentDocument> dc = [Select id, Title From ContentDocument];

List<ContentWorkspaceDoc> cwd = [Select ContentDocumentId From ContentWorkspaceDoc Where ContentWorkspaceId = '0580Y000000BjaBQAS'];


List<ContentWorkspaceDoc> temp = new List<ContentWorkspaceDoc>();

for(ContentDocument cd: dc){
ContentWorkspaceDoc cwd = new ContentWorkspaceDoc();
cwd.ContentDocumentId = cd.Id;
cwd.ContentWorkspaceId = '0580Y000000BjaBQAS';
temp.add(cwd);
}

insert cwd;
```

Comment: Hi @Daniela Cerqueira, welcome to SFSE, pelase take some time to read [ask] and take the [tour] in order to get familiar with the forum. Please include what you have tried, or where you are stuck. We will be more than ahppy to assist once you have **[edit]** ed your psot with the above. Note that this site is not a free coding service, we expect you to do a best effort, and research prior to posting here. Thanks.

Comment: thanks for updating with your code. What is the current behavior? what does nto seem to work ? what is the expected behavior, if you have any errors in your console, make sure you include them VERBATIM, try addind system.debug logs if needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ContentWorkspace**

> Represents a content library. This object is available in versions
>   17.0 and later. This object does not apply to personal libraries.

**ContentWorkspaceDoc**

> Represents a link between a document and a public library in
>   Salesforce CRM Content. This object is available in versions 17.0 and
>   later.This object does not apply to documents and versions in a personal library.

For adding a file with the library, you need is:-

```
      List<ContentDocument> dc = [Select id From ContentDocument];
//you need to query the library
    ContentWorkspace shareWorkspace = [select id from ContentWorkspace limit 1];
    List<ContentWorkspaceDoc> temp = new List<ContentWorkspaceDoc>();     
    for(ContentDocument cdoc:dc){
        ContentWorkspaceDoc docLink = new ContentWorkspaceDoc();
        docLink.ContentDocumentId = cdoc.id;
        docLink.ContentWorkspaceId = shareWorkspace.id; //assign the library id where you want to assign
        temp.add(docLink);
    }
    insert temp;
    system.debug(temp);
```

**note:-** you need to assign ContentWorkspaceDoc.ContentWorkspaceId of id type ContentWorkspace. This is where you are wrong in your code.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: it works perfectly !!!! :)